# Deleting table of a deleted app using South

Tags: django, django-south

In my project I had an app `push_notifications` which was a copy of the [Django push notifications app](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications), with some fields of the models modified.

I deleted this copied app to use the original package. Now I need to delete the tables of the old copied `push_notifications` app in my DB and run the initial migration of the original package.

I know I can use [South dependencies](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html) to first delete the old table when migrating `push_notifications` using something like , but I do not know in which migration I should write this dependency?

Anybody can help?